# How many ways can 8 boxes be arranged taking 3 at a time?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am not clearly understanding this question. What exactly does taking 3 at a time mean? I thought the answer would be 8**P**3 × 5**P**3 × 2!. You first select 3 boxes out of 8 and those can be arranged 3! ways, then select 3 boxes out of 5 and those can be arranged 3! ways, and finally, the last 2 boxes can be arranged 2! ways. However, this is wrong.

The real answer is 336.

Comment: It means, apparently, how many ways can you arrange $3$ boxes (books?) selected from $8$?  $336=8\cdot7\cdot6$

Comment: The wording seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use the following formula: You have $8$ digits, and how many $3$ digit numbers you can create, then $8\times(8-1)\times(8-2)=336$.

The idea is that in your first choice you have 8 boxes from which you can choose. Then after you take out one, you will be left with 7 to choose from, and so on.